# Textbox dimension inside Bootstrap Modal

Tags: textbox, bootstrap-modal

I have a textbox inside a Bootstrap Modal; here you can see an output example:

[image: Modalwithtextbox]

The yellow section is not part of original response; it's my add to show that the textbox has a default dimension and this one does not coincide with the modal size.

My purpose is to fill the yellow part with the textbox; in other words, I would that the textbox size coincide with the modal size. The question is: is there a way to perform this? 
I add that in modal, the textbox is not part of form section, as you can see in the code:

```
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Editing Menu</h4>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">
                              <textarea id='areaforinfo' readonly></textarea>
                              <form id="updateeventsform2" class="form-horizontal">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label"
                                          for="inputNotes">Notes</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                                    id="newnote" name ="newnote" placeholder="Put here the note"/>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for = "type" class = "col-sm-2 control-label">Status</label>
                             <div class = "col-sm-10">
                            <select class = "form-control" id = "newstatus" name="newstatus">
                            <option value="open">open</option>
                                <option value="closed">closed</option>
                            </select>
                         </div>
                              </div>
                             </form>
                            </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
```

Should I put the textbox code inside form section?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the textbox inside the form and add the class attribute; the final result is:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form id="updateeventsform2" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for='areaforinfo'>Message</label>
        <textarea class = "form-control" id='areaforinfo' style="min-width: 100%" readonly></textarea>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```